# Can I show the git diff status on a per-line basis?

Tags: git

I'd like to be able to see which lines in my file have been edited relative to the current git head, is there any way I can do this?

In particular, I'd like to be able to tell if a line was added or modified as I would by looking at the git diff.

Comment: Would a full diff be ok? If that is the case [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Gdiff` would be perfect.

Answer (score 4):

[gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) and [signify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify) are two plugins I know of which provide this sort of functionality.  When a buffer is saved, the sign column is updated to show where lines have been added/modified/deleted.

gitgutter is Git specific, while signify supports multiple version control systems.

<sup><sub>N.B., I'm a collaborator on signify.</sub></sup>

Comment: I made a similar [plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/changesPlugin)